# .openrecordsource "run-time error '91'"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba

I'm having an issue with the following lines of code, I feel its something simple but I can't put my finger on it. I get a Run-time error '91' object variable or with block variable not set error. The error happens on the `rsc.OpenRecordSet...` line. `BadgeV` is a number, I have the DAO reference installed, It is pulling from a linked sql server table where I have a primary key and identity. What am I missing?

```
Function FNC_Scan()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsc As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    rsc.OpenRecordset ("SELECT dbo_ScanData.CardID, dbo_ScanData.Complete FROM dbo_ScanData WHERE (((dbo_ScanData.CardID)= Forms![Scan]!BadgeV))) AND ((dbo_ScanData.Complete)=0));")

    If rsc.EOF Then
        MsgBox "new item"
    Else
        MsgBox "Append Item"
    End If

    Set rsc = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Set rsc = db.OpenRecordset ("SELECT dbo_ScanData.CardID, dbo_ScanData.Complete FROM dbo_ScanData WHERE dbo_ScanData.CardID=" & Forms![Scan]!BadgeV & " AND dbo_ScanData.Complete=0")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
set rsc = db.OpenRecordset(...)
```

instead of

```
rsc.OpenRecordset(...)
```

Comment: Thanks that helped but now I get a Run-time error 3061 Too few parameters. Expected 1. Any insight?

Comment: Check the spelling of the field names--This usually means that the engine found a name that it didn't find in the underlying table.

Comment: Thanks everyone, here is my full solution in case it will help someone else